# FOSUserBundle not applying User entity changes

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have just installed FosUserBundle in a Symfony version 2.3.3 application.
I'm able to manage users, login, register and whatnot but changes I make to my User class in MyApp\UserBundle\Entity aren't being applied when I run app/console doctrine:schema:update

The database structure contains:
id,
username,
username_canonical,
email,
email_canonical,
enabled,
salt,
password,
last_login,
locked,
expired,
expires_at,
confirmation_token,
password_requested_at,
roles,
credentials_expired,
credentials_expire_at

The field that I have added, rate, isnt being created in the database structure no matter what I do.

Inside /app/AppKernel.php

```
        new MyApp\UserBundle\MyAppUserBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```

Inside /app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
```

And inside /src/MyApp/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rate", type="integer")
     */
    private $rate;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set token
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return User
     */
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get token
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * Set rate
     *
     * @param integer $rate
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRate($rate)
    {
        $this->rate = $rate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rate
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getRate()
    {
        return $this->rate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the result of `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`?

Comment: Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Comment: Have you updated the actual mappings in `/src/MyApp/UserBundle/Rescources/doctrine/user.orm.whatever` with your new fields?

Comment: I would refer you to the documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Also, updating to the latest version of FOSUserBundle fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the constructor, clear the cache and try `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

> namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;
>
> use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser; use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as
>   ORM;
>
> /**  * @ORM\Entity  * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")  */ class User
>   extends BaseUser {
>       /**
>        * @ORM\Id
>        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
>        */
>       protected $id;
>
> ```
> public function __construct()
> {
>     parent::__construct();
>     // your own logic
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: have added the constructor, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add MyUserBundle mappings to your config.yml file:

```
doctrine: 
    orm:
           mappings:
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                MyUserBundle: ~
```

Comment: I have added these mappings, still isnt adding the fields

Comment: Did you actually have to add MyUserBundle to the mapping or was it already in there?

Comment: Does MyUserBundle have other entities which use yaml or xml mappings?  Cannot mix annotation/yml/xml in on bundle.

Comment: And what about token?  Is it getting mapped?